# Economy incept vs Mage Sight and Scrutinize Resonance

Tags: mage-the-awakening, demon-the-descent, chronicles-of-darkness-2e

I'm having some trouble with the angels' Economy incept. It's clear that when a power affects the angel, the power's activator must pay (rank) energy.

But what about Mage Sight? If a mage uses Mage Sight in the vicinity of the angel and just looks at it does he also have to pay (rank) mana for that?

And in addition to that, as the two are linked, is Scrutinize. Does each roll invoke the cost? Or is it only invoked once?

Note that this question is specifically about angels who are in cover and thus material.

Comment: @Ahriman don't forget angels can manifest and an angel in cover is a physical being until it deactivates the cover then it gets into twilight state again. Thus in the above the question mostly involves angels who are in an active cover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

In Mage 1st edition Mage Sight is an Unveiling spell. The target of the spell is typically the mage herself, and the effect of the spell is to expand the senses of the target, to allow her to clearly perceive supernatural powers and resonance. While under the effects of Mage Sight, the mage can scrutinize what she is seeing to drive meaning out of it. However, the scrutiny roll is not a supernatural power, it is the mage applying her occult knowledge to the information been exposed through Mage Sight.

On the other hand, a Knowing or Unveiling spell directed at the Angel itself would be affected.